# A matching like problem

Tags: co.combinatorics, computer-science

Consider  finite sets S and R and a symmetric function $f:S\times S\rightarrow R$. Let $M$ be a matching, ie a partition of $S$ into subsets of size 2.  For each matching can count the number of pairs that map to each value of $R,$ $count(f,M,r)$ is the number of pairs in the matching that map to $R$ and 
$count(f,M)=\max_r count(f,M,r)$.  I'm interested in $count(f) = max_M count(f,M)$ over all possible matchings.

For example, if $R=\{0,1\}$ we can think of  $r=0$ as denoting a red edge in the graph and $r=1$ as a blue edge.  Then $count(f)$ is the maximum of the maximum red edge matching and blue edge matching.  In this case, I've done some analysis and think that $count(f)\geq(2/3)|S|/2$ for every f in this case. (Note that there are $|S|/2$ pairs which is the maximum possible value for $count(f)$ so I will think of this as a $2/3-$solution.)

I'm particularly interested in the case where $R=S,$ but haven't made much progress.  I'd be interested in suggestions or pointers to related problems.

Edit: fixed a factor of 2 in my conjecture.

Comment: I guess you mean that count(f) is at least 2/3 of the number of edges (pairs)? It's still not true when S has 4 elements, but maybe asymptotically? What is the analysis that you have done?

Comment: If we have $3k-1$ vertices and all edges are colored with two colors, we may find $k$ disjoint edges of the same color. This may be proved by induction. Base $k=1$ is clear. Assume that $k\geqslant 2$ and prove the above claim assuming that for $k-1$ it holds. If all edges have the same color, this is clear. Otherwise there exist two edges $ab,ac$ of different color which share a common vertex. Remove $a,b,c$, apply induction proposition and add an edge $ab$ or $ac$.

Comment: ... but for $3k-2$ vertices this is not always possible: consider a red clique on $2k-1$ vertices and all other edges blue.

Comment: It still is not clear what do you ask when $R=S$.

Comment: What you are interested in is just the maximal number of monocolor edges, right?

Comment: Even if $|R|=|S|-2$, there may be no two disjoint monocolor edges: start with monocolor $K_3$, then add a vertex and a new color for all its edges, repeat. But if $|R|=|S|-3\geq1$, then two monocolor disjoint edges can always be found.

Comment: @FedorPetrov  thanks, I think that approximately proves my conjecture.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov  thanks, that seems to solve the case I was ultimately interested in.  (Alas, I was hoping for a more positive result...)

Comment: This isn't just a matching-*like* problem. It's asking for the largest monocolour matching in a complete undirected edge-coloured graph.

Comment: @PeterTaylor thanks, I didn't know what is was called.